# Как применять функцию построчно

Tags: python, математика, csv, lambda

```
with open('gaze.csv', 'r') as gaze:
 gaze_1_x, gaze_0_x, gaze_1_y, gaze_0_y, gaze_1_z, gaze_0_z = tuple(cols)
 for i in range(len(gaze_0_x)):
    x = float(gaze_1_x[i]) - float(gaze_0_x[i])
    y = float(gaze_1_y[i]) - float(gaze_0_y[i])
    z = float(gaze_1_z[i]) - float(gaze_0_z[i])
    for line in gaze.readlines():
        g = lambda x, y, z: ((x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5, [x, y, z])
        print(g)
```

В итоге:
function lambda at 0x0DFA3A08 на каждую строку файла. 
Что я делаю не так?

З.Ы.
нужно подставить значения из каждой строки в функцию и получить оригинальный ответ на каждую строку. При игрищах с кодом получалось максимум безумное сложение-перемножение аргументов всех столбцов с их последующей подстановкой.

Comment: И не должна ли lambda автоматически возвращать значение?

Comment: а зачем на каждой итерации создавать лямбду? вам ведь нужно просто выполнить `((x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5`? Тогда просто: `g = (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5`. Лямбда вернет значение если у нее вызвать `()`: `(lambda x, y, z: (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5)(x, y, z)`

Comment: При этом получается только одна цифра, которая и выводится на каждую строку, но не разные значения, в чем и проблема. :с

Comment: Ну дык, как написали, так и получили. Т.к. в вопросе не написали желаемый результат и входные строки, приходится играть с вами в загадки :) Я снова попытаюсь угадать: `g = (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5, [x, y, z]` :)

Comment: Csv формата:
gaze_0_x, gaze_0_y, gaze_0_z, gaze_1_x, gaze_1_y, gaze_1_z
0.294526,0.302667,-0.906447,-0.244304,0.30529,-0.920388
0.300238,0.358409,-0.883968,-0.26185,0.359709,-0.895569
0.293682,0.298443,-0.90812,-0.245462,0.291718,-0.924472

Я написала про то, что хочу получить - решение по формуле построчно, но вот формат вводных строк не указала.
Я открываю файл, делаю по колонкам кортежи, после чего провожу с ними операции для вычисления x, y, z, для каждой строки, а потом хочу x, y, z из каждой строки применить в формулу, чтоб найти уникальное решение для каждой.

Comment: одно и тоже значение выходит у вас потому что x,y,z вы вне цикла определяете. Похоже, их значения находятся в на каждой строке в `for line in gaze.readlines()`. Правильно?

Comment: Да. Значит, нужно задать это как главный цикл и `for i in range(len(gaze_0_x)):` как подцикл? 
Все равно не получается, выдает повторяющуюся строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулями [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) и [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read CSV into a pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\.data\784492.csv')
# calculate euclidean distance and save it as a new DF column
df['dist'] = np.linalg.norm(df.filter(like='gaze_1').values
                            - df.filter(like='gaze_0').values,
                            axis=1)
```

Результат:

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]:
   gaze_0_x  gaze_0_y  gaze_0_z  gaze_1_x  gaze_1_y  gaze_1_z      dist
0  0.294526  0.302667 -0.906447 -0.244304  0.305290 -0.920388  0.539017
1  0.300238  0.358409 -0.883968 -0.261850  0.359709 -0.895569  0.562209
2  0.293682  0.298443 -0.908120 -0.245462  0.291718 -0.924472  0.539434
```

PS модули Numpy/Pandas/scipy/sklearn - позволяют производить векторизированные вычисления, что обычно на порядки быстрее по сравнению с решениями использующими (вложенные) циклы. Кроме того код выглядит гораздо короче и понятнее (после короткого ознакомления)...

PPS проблема в вашем коде в том, что вы выводите на печать указатель на lambda функцию, вместо результата вызова функции с параметрами:

```
print(g(x,y,z))
```

Пример:

```
In [71]: f = lambda a,b: max(a,b)

In [72]: print(f)
<function <lambda> at 0x000000000B748F28>

In [73]: print(f(1,2))
2
```

Comment: О, это снова Вы. Спасибо за помощь еще раз. с:
На самом деле, немного глупо с моей стороны, но я все еще продолжала использовать дефолтный csv модуль, но теперь вижу, что стоит его дропнуть. 
Это действительно выглядит по-человечески.